# sorting array of date objects error javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I am getting a weird error, couldn't figure it out. I have an array of date objects (AngularJS) and I want to sort them. I am doing as below

```
console.log(tempDates);
tempDates.sort( function(a, b) {
    return a-b;
});
console.log(tempDates);
```

The problem is the tempDates array is getting modified, i.e, the date values are getting modified. Is the custom sort function wrong? / what am I missing?

the original tempDates -

```
["Jun 19", "Jun 26", "Jul  3", "Jul 10", "Jul 17", "Jul 24", "Jul 31", "Aug  7", "Aug 14", "Aug 21", "Aug 28", "Sep  4", "Sep 11"]
```

after sorting, it is

```
["Jun 19", "Jun 26", "Jul  1", "Jul  3", "Jul 10", "Jul 17", "Jul 24", "Aug  7", "Aug 14", "Aug 21", "Aug 28", "Sep  4", "Sep 11"]
```

(Please note that the array consists of DATE objects, the console output that I put is just for readability)

The dates are changing, like "Jul 1" is appearing out of nowhere and "Jul 31" is removed from the list. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: @V.J. Quote from OP: "Please note that the array consists of DATE objects, the console output that I put is just for readability"

Comment: @Sirko: The `-` operator will do a `valueOf`(hint:number) on the `Date` instances, which will get the same value `getTime` does. Subtracting `Date` instances is fine.

Comment: I tried a.getTime()-b.getTime(), still I am getting the same output....
@V.J. The array consists of date objects, I put that format just for readability

Comment: `@swordfish12`: Your code will work fine (proof: http://jsfiddle.net/cx9on9ph/ -- I've randomized the initial dates so we can actually see the sorting), and will *not* modify the `Date` objects in the array. The behavior you're seeing is coming from something else in the code that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: This part is an independent function, and the array exists only in this scope. Moreover, I am printing the array just before sorting and just after sorting.

Comment: We can't help you with code we can't see.

Comment: As T.J. said, the `.sort()` function does not modify the objects in the array, it just moves them around.  So, either you are mistaken that they have been modified or something else you have not disclosed is changing the objects.  `.sort()` is not doing it.  Remember that objects can be pointed to by many different variables.  You don't automatically get independent copies just because you put them in an array.

Comment: You could be running into the [well-known console log confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349008/weird-console-logbehavior-in-chrome) -- e.g., something **later** is modifying the dates, and then you expand what you logged *earlier* and you see the change. Here's an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/cx9on9ph/1/ You can verify that by using `console.log(JSON.stringify(tempDates))` so what gets logged is a string that won't change.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7uyj6b9d/ I've tried to test with two different approach: your (return a - b) and by returing 1, 0 or -1 using > and < conditions. In any of the cases the sort worked perfectly, I suspect that you either are confonding your logs in someway or you have some not-well formed date objects in your array.

Comment: `sort()` swaps your array elements around to make them in order. Are you sure your `tempDates` actually lose some elements?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, solved the problem, the mistake - this was inside a $http.get success method, and another (asynchronous http call) process was modifying the array

Comment: @swordfish12: Glad you got it figured out! :-) (And thanks for saying what it was, I'm always curious.) Since the question probably won't be useful to others, probably best to delete it with the "delete" link under it. Again, glad you got it sorted. (Ugh! No pun intended.) Best,

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting date objects, not numbers. To sort them as numbers, you would have to do something like this:

```
console.log(tempDates);
tempDates.sort( function(a, b) {
    return a.getTime() - b.getTime(); 
});
console.log(tempDates);
```

.getTime() will convert the string representation of the date to an actual number. (Milliseconds since 1970/01/01)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I figured it out, there was a problem due to asynchronous http call and another part of the code was modifying the data.

Comment: Comparison of date objects is allowed. So (a.getTime() - b.getTime()) will be same as (a-b)